# Fundamental group of $K\# K/\{3\text{ points}\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, klein-bottle

The fundamental group of Klein bottle has been well discussed in many materials, I'm think if it is requested to calculate the fundamental group of $K\# K/\{3\text{ points}\}$ or even more generally $K\# K/\{n\text{ points}\}$ where $K$ is the Klein bottle. I found it might has deformation retraction onto Mobius band with $n$ circles but not very sure. I'm looking forward to idea on it

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout  They are similar, but definitely not the same question.

Comment: @Batominovski you've got any idea on the K#K/\{3 points\} one ?

Comment: Do you know the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem?

Comment: @JohnHughes no not very familiar with it

Comment: The strategy in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2958659/the-fundamental-group-of-klein-bottle-3pt/2958694#2958694) does not change at all for $\Sigma \setminus \{n \text{ points}\}$ for any closed surface $\Sigma$ or any $n>0$. You only need to know the Euler characteristic of a surface with a few punctures to determine its fundamental group. And this is straghtforward by the inclusion-exclusion principle $\chi(A \cup B) = \chi(A) + \chi(B) - \chi(A \cap B)$ for $A$ and $B$ both open.